# Can't figure out Beautifulsoup find() command for this HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find

I am trying to scrape some info from a page with python and Beautiful soup and i cant seem to write the right path to what i need, the html is:

```
<div class="operator active" data-operator_name="Etisalat" data- 
operator_id="5"><div class="operator_name_etisalat"></div></div>
```

And i am trying to get that operator name "Etisalat", i got this far:

```
def list_contries():

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('international_country'))
select.select_by_visible_text('France')
request = requests.get("https://mobilerecharge.com/buy/mobile_recharge?country=Afghanistan&operator=Etisalat")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
# print(soup.prettify())
prov=soup.find("div", {"class": "operator active"})['data-operator_name']
# prov = soup.find("div", {"class": "operator deselected"})
print(prov)
operator = (prov.text.strip())
```

But this just returns a NoneType .. so something is not right, can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Your solution works for me! Just copied your html as string, parsed it with BeautifulSoup and used your find(...) `>>> 'Etisalat'`. could you post the rest of your code

Comment: I'm gonna speculate that within `soup`, the class isn't actually `operator active` but in the DOM it is. That may be the reason why you're not getting a result.

Comment: Edited the question with the rest of the code. Thanks

Comment: first issue is that requests dont process javascript, and the page you are getting is different from the one you see by inspecting element. You should check it by opening page source in new tab [ctrl]+U.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS selector. CSS selector `[data-operator_name]` will select any tag with attribute `data-operator_name`. Example with Beautiful Soup:

```
data = """<div class="operator active" data-operator_name="Etisalat" data-
operator_id="5"><div class="operator_name_etisalat"></div></div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('[data-operator_name]')['data-operator_name'])
```

This will print:

```
Etisalat
```

**EDIT:**

To select multiple tags with attribute "data-operator_name", use `.select()` method:

```
data = """<div class="operator active" data-operator_name="Etisalat" data-
operator_id="5"><div class="operator_name_etisalat"></div></div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
for tag in soup.select('[data-operator_name]'):
    print(tag['data-operator_name'])
```

Comment: Hmm thanks mate, but i need to find multiple operators not just one. the code needs to be findall() instead of find() i'm just checking and testing with find().

Comment: @miloshIra then just use `select()`, not `select_one()`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Now it is grabbing all sorts of stuff.. bunch of stuff i don't need. I think it will work better with find() and find_all if i manage to make it work since it also includes div and class.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, when I access the link from the browser, I am not able to see the field you are after unless I inspect the element. Hence, I have used Selenium in my answer.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

scrapeLink = 'https://mobilerecharge.com/buy/mobile_recharge?country=Afghanistan&operator=Etisalat'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(scrapeLink)
html = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
operator = len(soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'operator'))

for i in range(operator):
    print(soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'operator')[i].get('data-operator_name'))
```

Output:

```
Roshan
Etisalat
MTN
Wireless
```

Comment: You are right. it is because of request module not running/fetching java script. Actual page source is different from requests gathered page source.